# RGB and CMYK Colour Modes

Tags: color, cmyk, print-production, rgb, color-spaces

I designed a book cover in Photoshop in RGB Colour Mode, as it was going to be used as an eBook cover. However, I now need to design a full wrap book jacket which needs to be in CMYK Colour Mode.

When I convert the colour modes, it loses its colour and desaturates a little. Is there any way I can convert it without losing the colours? I'm really struggling!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your vision does not actually work in a way where this is important. Do not compare the two images change walk away and try to make the image as good as it can be. See vision adapts to condition, but yes if you keep comparing to the rgb image it will look more saturated, because it can be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem converting color from RGB to CMYK for print](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/problem-converting-color-from-rgb-to-cmyk-for-print)

Answer (score 3):

No way in this universe CMYK will look identical to RGB. You need to let go of that idea and try to find a compromise.

In general yes, any CMYK conversion will look more washed out, versus a brighter, more intense RGB version of the same file.

The reasons are technical and feel free to research that, it is a common question, many have asked, and many have explained:

- [Problem converting color from RGB to CMYK for print](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/problem-converting-color-from-rgb-to-cmyk-for-print)
- [RGB and CMYK: Why both?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7815/rgb-and-cmyk-why-both)
- [RGB to CMYK conversion problem](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110787/rgb-to-cmyk-conversion-problem)